# Cocoapods: cocoapods(0.28.0) manages 3rdparty libs issue

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I use cocoapods(0.28.0) to manage 3rdparty libs in my Xcode(5.0.2) project. All things look good when running the project on iOS Simulator, but I meet a problem when running that on device(iOS 6 and iOS 7). The error message is:

> dyld: Symbol not found: _UIFontTextStyleHeadline

I searched the code, and found only SVProgressHUD(one 3rdparty lib managed by cocoapods) using `UIFontTextStyleHeadline` like this:

> ```
> #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 70000
>     return [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline];
> #else
>     return [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
> #endif
> ```

After I removed cocoapods and dragged the SVProgressHUD directly to my project, the problem was gone.

How to solve this problem if I don't want to remove cocoapods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the iOS Deployment target of the target Pods-SVProgressHUD, in the Pods project, to iOS 6.x.